# Mark an endpoint as deprecated with camel-swagger-java

Tags: java, apache-camel, swagger, openapi

Is there a way to mark a particular endpoint as deprecated in swagger using the modules camel-swagger-java or camel-openapi-java?

Reviewing the [openapi v2 specification](https://swagger.io/specification/v2/) is possible to add the "deprecated: true" property to the documentation in order to deprecate and endpoint but I can't find a way to implement this using camel swagger or camel openapi. I was testing both demo projects from camel ([rest swagger example](https://github.com/apache/camel-spring-boot-examples/tree/main/rest-swagger) and [rest openapi example](https://github.com/apache/camel-spring-boot-examples/tree/main/rest-openapi)) and I couldn't implement this behaviour.

Is there something that I'm missing? I was also trying to find a ticket in [Camel's Jira portal](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/CAMEL/issues/CAMEL-16553?filter=allopenissues) related to this issue and I didn't find any.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this functionality was not present in camel (nor for swagger neither openapi) so I created a [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-16558) for this. It was implemented by someone in the community and It's going to be ready for the next camel release.

**UPDATE**

The improvement was done and is ready in Camel 3.10.0 onwards.